# Can we create iOS app with swift and obj c both?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, swift

Can we create iOS app with swift and obj c both.My half app is made using OBJ-C and just want to improve apps performance so is that possible to use swift in between

Comment: I am highly skeptical of Apple's claims of large performance increases with Swift. I suspect that in their benchmarks they selected some worst-case Objective-C to run against. I am an old assembler programmer, and write my code using a blend of C and Objective C, optimizing for performance and memory efficiency. I'd be interested in putting my code up against a swift version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just need to follow this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Current link doesn't direct to the correct apple url. Looks like it has been archived or no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

You have to add objc header #imports in the `<module name>-Bridging-Header.h` that you want to make available in swift, and you can use swift code from objc by importing the `<module name>-Swift.h` file in your objc code.

Note that the latter header file is automatically generated when building, and it is not visible in the project navigator - but you can open it by cmd+click-ing its name in an existing #import. Also to note that if compilation fails, most likely the file will not be generated.

Last, I highly recommend that you avoid circular references between objc and swift - for instance, creating a `SwiftClass`, inherited from `BaseObjcClass`, and using `SwiftClass` from objc - I've experienced that it doesn't work (compilation errors), and I am not aware of any workaround

Answer (score 1):

Apple’s intention to replace the Objective-C language using Swift, it is not practical in the short term simply due to the fact that developers are deeply entrenched in Objective-C. Rather than force Swift down the developer’s throat, Apple has made it easy to allow Objective-C to interoperate with Swift.

http://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-objective-c-and-swift-together-ios-apps

Answer (score 0):

Dec 2018 - I found this useful YouTube video that helps explain what files you need to add and how to make the connections.

[YouTube - How to use Swift and Objective-C in the same project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDk5zXCFe8)